# Java Mail in JMeter - getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not yet implemented for Mailing functionality

Tags: java, jmeter, mailing

I need help/ guidance to resolve below issue.

I have created java mailing functionality in JMeter. It is working fine if I ran by using JMeter tool and getting mails to our wheels id also. But same code if I run with maven framework we are getting below error message.

```
  Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
  MimeMessage  msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

The following error happens during the creation of the MIME message:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not yet implemented
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~
```

Comment: Hi some one please help me hear